# Individuals in multiple departments affecting grand total count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12.2

I have a report I am trying to simplify but I am running into an issue.

(Undesired) The rows/columns of the report currently look like the following.

| Department | Total | Probation (%) | Suspended (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Employees | 32 | 16.3 | 1.4 |
| All Teams | 30 | 23.5 | 2.2 |
| Total Men's Teams | 10 | 14.8 | 2.8 |
| Total Women's Teams | 10 | 34.3 | 1.4 |
| Men's Wear | 10 | 5.9 | 0.0 |
| Women's Wear | 10 | 21.4 | 0.0 |
| UniSec Wear | 10 | 15.0 | 6.3 |

This is happening because two people work on two teams. One person works in Mens Wear and UniSex Wear, and one person works in Women's Wear and UniSex Wear. The below table has records like this.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Men's Wear |
| 1234 | UniSex Wear |
| 9876 | Women's Wear |
| 9876 | UniSex Wear |

(Desired) Im looking for something like this.

| Department | Total | Probation (%) | Suspended (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Employees | 30 | 16.3 | 1.4 |
| All Teams | 30 | 23.5 | 2.2 |
| Total Men's Teams | 10 | 14.8 | 2.8 |
| Total Women's Teams | 10 | 34.3 | 1.4 |
| Men's Wear | 10 | 5.9 | 0.0 |
| Women's Wear | 10 | 21.4 | 0.0 |
| UniSec Wear | 10 | 15.0 | 6.3 |

I have thought about using LISTAGG() on Col2 to get this affect.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Men's Wear,UniSex Wear |
| 9876 | Women's Wear,UniSex Wear |

Using LISTAGG() gives me the correct count for "All Employees" but then I get groupings of "Men's Wear,UniSex Wear" instead of a separate one for "Men's Wear" and one for "UniSex Wear". Is it possible to group by the individual comma separated values in Col2 after they have been LISTAGG()'ed, or is there a better way of achieving my end results?

Any assistance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should rephrase your question by showing the original starting data, along with the current output and what output you actually want to see.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the only problem is the number of total employees? Because you are using `COUNT(*)` and not `COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise correcting the All_Employees data alone instead of doing the LISTAGG.
OR
Use a separate table to LISTAGG and un-LISTAGG your data which is different from the original table used to calculate the Total, Probation and Suspended data

For un-LISTAGG you can use the below example where table_two is your source table.

```
    with  
    d2 as (
      select 
        distinct id, 
        regexp_substr(
          products, '[^,]+', 1, column_value
        ) as products 
      from 
        table_two cross 
        join TABLE(
          Cast(
            MULTISET (
              SELECT 
                LEVEL 
              FROM 
                dual CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(products, '[^,]+')
            ) AS sys.ODCINUMBERLIST
          )
        )
    ) 
    SELECT 
      ID, 
      PRODUCTS 
    FROM 
      d2;
```